# Windows network folder directory list inconsistent when viewed from two different client machines

Tags: windows, permissions, filesystems, directory, share

I am on a corporate network using Windows.  There is a network share provided by a NetApp appliance. When I log on to two different machines and view the network drive, I see inconsistent directory listings. From one client machine I see `T:\test` as having two files.  From another client machines I see `T:\test` as having around 20 files.

I have confirmed ~100% that these are the same folders because the overlapping files are consistent.

What would cause two different machines to see different directory listing results when I am using the same windows client operating system account to map the drives?

Answer (score 1):

I've often seen this when client machines have Offline Files enabled for a given share.

Same user, same share, different files on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

Darn.  It was a different userid afterall.  My Windows admin gave me bad info because she had confused herself with different client accounts.